# Sending structures to functions in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I have a sample piece of code and I had a question about it. Here is the code. My questions are comments near the bottom of the code and I was wondering if anyone could help out. Getting mixed up here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
    char make[30];
    char model[30];
    int year;
};

struct car f(struct car c);

int main(void)
{
    struct car c1 = {"Ford", "Mustang", 2014}, c2;
    c2 = c1;

    printf("%s, %s, %d\n", c1.make, c1.model, c1.year);
    c2 = f(c1);
    printf("%s, %s, %d\n", c2.make, c2.model, c2.year);
}

struct car f(struct car c) /* Is car here referring to the structure at the very top
                             of the program, so it knows what structure to put it? */
{
    struct car temp = c;  /* What exactly is c in this function and why copy it? */
    strcpy(temp.model, "Explorer");
    temp.year += 5;

    return temp;
}
```

The code prints:

```
Ford, Mustang, 2014
Ford, Explorer, 2019
```

Comment: `struct car c` in `f()` is a copy of `c1` from `main()`.  `c1` is not altered by `f(c1)`.

Comment: thanks. so the c in function f is a c1 as a string? could i just print it by using printf("%s",c)??

Comment: No.  `c` is a copy of the structure.  `c` is a structure, not a string.

Comment: `struct car temp = c;` is pointless, you could just work on `c` in the function and return `c`

Comment: passing a struct by value is a very bad idea as it causes a chunk of ram, large enough to hold the struct, to be permanently allocated and the struct copied into it.  Much better to pass a ptr to the struct, which will be passed on the stack

Comment: @Jovis13 I am now realizing that you almost never 'accept' any answers. Please consider that people volunteer a lot of time answering your own questions. As of this writing, out of 15 questions you asked, *only 1* has an accepted answer. Nobody other than you can know if questions were fully answered of course, but I can hardly imagine that all these questions were not acceptably answered?

Answer (score 4):

`struct car` is a type, which is defined at the top of your program.  So `struct car f(struct car c)` is a function named `f` that takes a `struct car` named `c` as a parameter, and returns another `struct car`.

The reason to make a copy of `c` is so that you can change one of them without affecting the other.  Since you passed `c` by value in this case, it doesn't really matter; you could edit `c` and then return it.  But if you'd passed it by reference (ie, passing a pointer to it), then modifying it would change the caller's copy, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `f()` the struct is copied and then passed in to the function. Any modifications made in the function will be discarded upon exit. However, you are passing out a struct which you then save and print. So, to answer your question, the `struct car` in the function is a temporary variable that does not directly refer back to anything external to the function.

If you want to directly modify a variable outside the function, then you will need to pass a pointer instead and dereference that pointer inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct car f(struct car c) /*is car here refering to the structure at the very top
                            of the program, so it knows what structure to put it?/*
```

`struct car` here is a `type 'struct car' defining X`. The `struct car` at the top defines the global type `struct car`. `X` refers to the function `f` that provides a return of type `struct car` and `c` an argument that expects a reference of type `struct car` (regardless what name it has). The struct car at the top has global scope, the function above expect an agrument such as `c1` or `c2` declared in main().